# Using Angular to append next set of results

Tags: angularjs

I have data that i'm getting from an external API via jsonp.

I have requested the first 10 results. This comes back as an object.

I have new call with a button to fetch the next 10 results from it's cache but it just overwrites the first set of returned data.

How can I get Angular to append or push each subsequent data to the bottom?

```
$scope.getEanApi = function(){
        devaFactory.searchRequest()
            .then(function(data){
            $scope.hotels = data.HotelListResponse.HotelList;           
            }).finally(function(){
        });
        return;
    };
    $scope.getEanApi();

    $scope.moreResults = function(){
        devaFactory.moreResults()
            .then(function(data){
            $scope.hotels = data.HotelListResponse.HotelList;
            angular.extend($scope.hotels,$scope.hotels);                  
            }).finally(function(){
        });
        return;
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's an array then do as below:

```
$scope.data = $scope.data.concat(newData);
```

However it changes array reference with merged array so if you've used `ng-repeat` then it will redraw for whole array. If you're using any animation then you may want to redraw for newly elements only so for that append your new array data manually by iterating through as below.

```
for(var j=0;j<newData.length;j++) {
     $scope.data.push(newData[j]);
}
```

If it's object then do

```
angular.extend($scope.data,newData);
```

Comment: It's an object. I have two functions in my controller. The parameters are slightly different. One that takes the first request and the other that fetches more data. The $scope.hotels needs to be the same in order to fill it in to the ng repeat.

Comment: as it's an object you can control order. all keys will automatically sorted in ascending order. You can use angular.extend which merge your new object with $scope.hotels.

Comment: It was an array after all not an object..$scope.data = $scope.data.concat(newData); worked..Thanks